# Engine oil reduction issue (On high RPM)

Tags: engine

I have an issue with my car engine oil reducing oil.I am using Toyota Passo 2011 model 1000cc and u atound 90k driven. I have purchased this car around 6months ago.in start i was not lookng at the engine oil,i jst start changing it aftr 250k. But 2 months back,i have checked the engine oil from dip stick,it was almost low.means on lower dip point.i was little worry and i jst changed the engine oil again.i have contacted wth one mechanics about this issue.he jst says its engine is weak and need to replace. I was li surprised by his ans. Anyways i start monitoring oil level regularly. Aftr few days i have a visit to ny home town which is almost 550km away.i traveled 550km without Ac on because i was also feeling some xtra force on engine with AC on,specially during the pickup,my speed was around 120km/hour. I have completed my visit and checked the oil level,which was perfect. I used to travel wthin the city as well but there was no oil level drop. I used to visit one ac mechanic for Ac checkup,he says its compressor is not working fine because of which engine is taking high current,thats why car engine is experience a force. He jst did the filter cleaning and refill the gas. After my return journey,i On the AC on full route and was travling at around 120 to 140km/hour. Which i reched back, and checked the engine oil next day, it was almost half on dip stick. I jst put oil again to maintain its level. One week back,i have changed the engine oil again and yesterday i have visit to another city around 250km away with AC on and speed around 120-140km/hour and same in return visit. Today i have checked the oil level which is again reduced to haf on dip stick. AC cooling is working fine but i am feeling extra force on engine.My question is that,on faulty ac compressor and on high speed,is it the case of my car engine oil reduction??? Or there may have some other problem in engine. As i have travelled around 700kms with  normal speed 115-120km/hour on motorway and 60 70km/hour in city but the oil level was not reduced. As soon as i start traveling on high speed with AC on, i feels the Oil level reduction happenes. Yours expert advise is required in this regards. Thank you.?

Comment: Can you determine where the missing oil is going? Dripping on the ground after vehicle shut off? Dripping on the ground while the vehicle is driving? Burning up in the combustion process, and ending up as gray smoke out the tail pipe? Or perhaps ending up mixed into the coolant system.